# How to display photos from amazon s3 bucket

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, bucket

I have uploaded images from nodejs to my bucket on s3 and want to display image from s3 bucket but get an error saying HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/1653479594543-great.jpg

Error thrown:
**

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following HttpExceptionWithStatus was thrown resolving an image codec:
HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 403, uri = https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/user.png
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/user.png", scale: 1.0) 
 Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/user.png", scale: 1.0): CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/user.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 404, uri = https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/https://heroku-url-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%20%28142%29.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**

I developed Flutter app to display image.

I have added policy statement like this below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1653479258815",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1653479249885",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::heroku-url-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please how can I fix it?

Comment: Is that the actual bucket name you are trying to use? Or did you change your bucket name in the question? Please edit your question to include the full error response from S3, not just the status code.

Comment: Okay sure. Yes the bucket is edited.

Comment: @MarkB, please I have included the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved. I followed an [article][1] and re-edit the policy statement

Before

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1653479258815",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1653479249885",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::heroku-url-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

After

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1653487082193",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1653487079423",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::heroku-sharpcall-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[1]: [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-s3-action-does-not-apply-to-resources#:~:text=To%20solve%20the%20%22Action%20Does,%3A%3A%3Amy%2Dbucket%2F*%20](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-s3-action-does-not-apply-to-resources#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20%22Action%20Does,%3A%3A%3Amy%2Dbucket%2F*%20)).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you filled the data and what I should replace it with and where to put this piece of code?